Breaking up effect for Android
I am trying to create an animation for an Android TextView. I want to break-up the text into tiny pieces and apply some physics simulation as it breaks up!.
I will probably need to implement a custom view and an Android ValueAnimator so I can control the time-step of the animation.
I have thought of creating a specific Paint object with a property that it paints with transparent, semi-transparent and opaque pixels and as time moves on increase the amount of transparent pixels in the animation. I would like the process to be random so I will probably will have to follow a Perlin-Noise algorithm.
How can I create an Android Paint object in the Canvas with these properties?
I have also thought of using a Github library called ShaderView found here ShaderView
Is it possible to work with shaders on the Android Canvas to create this 2D effect?
Thanks for any suggestions!
